# How did Haman know Moshe Rabeinu's Yahrzeit but not his Birthday?

Tags: purim, tractate-megillah, adar, haman

I remember learning some years ago in Gemarah [Megillah 13:](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13b.15?with=all) that when Haman drew lots he was happy it landed in Adar since it is the month that Moshe Rabeinu died. However, he didn't know that Moshe Rabeinu was born in that month as well.

1. How and why would Haman know the birthdate of a Jewish leader? (i.e. why would a gentile care to know Jewish trivia?)
2. Say Haman knew it from some Jewish sources, 
   Wouldn't it make sense for someone who heard, that on the 7th day of Adar is Moshe Rabeinu's Yahrzeit, would hear in the same sentence, that on THE VERY SAME DAY was Moshe Rabeinu's birthday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw an answer in the Sefer Pirsumei Nissa p: 246 and I'll try to translate:

It is brought down in the Sefer Yaaros D'vash
( ח"ב דרוש י"ז/ח"א דרוש ג'/ח"ב דרוש ב' ודרוש י"ג)
The reason Haman did not know that the 7th of Adar was Moshe Rabeinu's Birthday is because it says in the Pasuk [(Shemot 2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.2.2)
 ותצפנה שלשה ירחים. ולא יכלה עוד הצפינו
*and they hid Him for three months and they could no longer hide Him.*

Moshe was born [6 months and 1 day](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.2.3.1) from when he was conceived. The Yidden know this. However the Mitzryim thought that Moshe was born after 9 months (and that is the reason that Moshe Rabeinu's parents did not have to hide Him until He was 3 months old). Therefore, Haman thought that Moshe's birthday was 3 months after his actual birthday!

Answer (score 7):

The מהרש"א on that Gemara explains that Moshe having died on the 7th of Adar is something which could be worked out from Scriptures, as the Gemara works it out on Kiddushin 38a (it says they wept for Moshe for 30 days, then Yehoshua told them they had three days before crossing the Yarden, and they came through the Yarden on the 10th day of the 1st month, so just work backwards and you get the 7th of Adar).

However, Moshe being born on that day is only learned through a Rabbinical derasha, and that was not known to Haman.

In terms of your first point, it is not that unusual to find in Rabbinic tradition the enemies of the Jewish people being strangely familiar with Scripture.

Comment: This is actually not that surprising even in modern times. 

There are many historical figures who we know the death date of but not the birthdate. For instance, Idi Amin (Y"S) was the dictator of Uganda for many years, but we don't know his birth year, let alone his birth date.